# Need to Refactor the SQL Query to reduce the execution time through CPP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

The below query execution takes more than two minutes. Using SQL Server.

```
Select  lastname
      , firstname
      , gender CASE WHEN TableB.orderno is null THEN TableA.EmpId ELSE TableB.orderno END as 'EmpId'
FRO TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB  ON TableA.EmpId = TableB.EmpId
WHERE TableA.userId = ? 
and TableA.findstring like '%Raj%' 
and '%Guptha%';
```

Planning to do indexing and refactoring the query to make the execution faster.
How to refactor the above query?

I tried to split up the query as below, Does the below split-up query as Query#1 & Query#2 is advisable?
How to pass the Query#1 result set(more than 2000 records) to Query#2 as an input in **CPP**?

**Query 1**:

```
Select EmpId 
FROM TableA 
WHERE findstring like '%Raj%' 
and '%Guptha%';
```

**Query 2**:

```
Select  lastname
      , firstname
      , gender CASE WHEN TableB.orderno is null THEN TableA.EmpId ELSE TableB.orderno END as 'EmpId'
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.EmpId = TableB.EmpId
WHERE TableA.userId = ? 
and TableA.EmpId IN (*RESULT OF Query 1*);
```

Comment: `and TableA.findstring like '%EMPFirstName%' and '%EMPLastName%'` isn't even valid SQL. But as Felipe says, not much you can do with a wildcard search. An index on `TableA.findstring` may help, because it allows SQL Server to load in the minimum amount of data to find the required records, still all of them, but only the one column per rercord. We need to see your plan.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add table and index definitions, as well as share the query plans via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: I have updated the correct values in the query string. The column 'findstring' has value of length 300 chars(firstname, lastname, date of joining, ssn etc..).We are searching firstname(Raj) & lastname(Guptha) from the value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any index could help you whit this query because of the usage of `like '%EMPFirstName%'` this is called a non [SARG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) parameter (since index are on the bottom a B-Tree implementation and the usage of % at the beginning and end will need to check all the index (or a very big part and make the engine to choose based on the cost)
Also, what's the idea of and '%EMPLastName%' you are not using against any column so it's true as default.

Can you post the execution plan for this query? You can upload to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and share the generated link

Comment: I have updated the correct values in the query string. The column 'findstring' has value of length 300 chars(firstname, lastname, date of joining, ssn etc..).We are searching firstname(Raj) & lastname(Guptha) from the value. Will query splitting reduce the execution time of the query? if yes,how could we do it in cpp

Comment: Like I say before, the index is in a B-Tree structure but if you use a wildcard (% mean no char, 1 char or n char) as a prefix and a postfix there is no way the algorithm can choose the correct path internally For example valid output of the expression %Raj% can be:
 - Raj
- Raj123
- Raj1
- 1Raj
- RajRaj
- 123Raj
- 123Raj123
You need to remove wildcard in some part of the expression and do some validation in the code to avoid the need of % in the front and the back of the string